# tf.layers.dense kernel initializer and regularizer

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

The tf.layers.dense function defined as:

```
tf.layers.dense(
    inputs,
    units,
    activation=None,
    use_bias=True,
    kernel_initializer=None,
    bias_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(),
    kernel_regularizer=None,
    bias_regularizer=None,
    activity_regularizer=None,
    trainable=True,
    name=None,
    reuse=None
)
```

has two optional arguments `kernel_initializer` and `kernel_regularizer`. I have two different regularization and initialization techniques of my own that I wish to experiment with. I am not keen on implementing the entire neural network from scratch. Could someone provide an example for supplying custom functions to these two arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do is to check the implementation of `initializer` and `regularizer` in tensorflow. For instance, the `variance_scaling_initializer` initializer is defined in this code: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/initializers.py#L62-L152

It is consituted of an `initializer` function with the following signature:

```
initializer(shape, dtype=dtype, partition_info=None)
```

that returns a tensor.

The regularizers are defined here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/regularizers.py